# how can I make windowless flash projector without a 3rd party application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, projector

i'm trying to finish an educational cdrom done in flash, how can i make a window less projector, or position the window on the center of the screen without a 3rd party software?

Comment: I don't think you can make anything without a window. Maybe someone can suggest a different solution if you describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're referring to hiding the window chrome, not hiding the window itself?

If you build your application with Air then you can create a chrome-less window (see the "Window chrome" section) and control the initial positioning:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=WorkingWithWindows_2.html

The only limitation with this method is that the computer must have the Air runtime installed and the application must also be installed before it can be used (which means the installing user must have administrative rights).

I would expect it to be be fairly easy to wrap the Air window management behaviour around your existing application.

If you can't convert the application to Air then the only other thing I can think of would be to use something like ScreenweaverHX (http://haxe.org/com/libs/swhx and http://screenweaver.org/doku.php) - sort of like an open-source, cross-platform project that gives you Air-like functionality. It does violate your 'no third-party' rule but those are the only two options I can think of.